# ¿Que hago para que el DataGridView no guarde la ultima fila?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Tengo un `DataGridView` en el cual ingreso datos directamente pero se crea una nueva fila y al momento de guardar en la Base de Datos se guarda con 0, y cuando quiero volver a llenarla me manda este error:

> **error**: 23505 duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Este es el código:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblarticulo.Rows)
{
    NpgsqlCommand guardar = new NpgsqlCommand("pro_factura", conexion, transaccion);
    guardar.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    guardar.Parameters.Clear();
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_codigod", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["column1"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_descripcion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column2"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["column3"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_precio", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["column4"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_valtotal", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["column5"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["column6"].Value = codigofactura.Text));
    guardar.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a la columna que te genera automaticamente, y siempre esta vacia?

Comment: si, me refiero a esa fila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas en que podrías hacerlo, yo lo haría usando un ciclo `for`de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblarticulo.Rows.Count -1; i++) 
{ 
    NpgsqlCommand guardar = new NpgsqlCommand("pro_factura", conexion, transaccion);
    guardar.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    guardar.Parameters.Clear();
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_codigod", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_descripcion", Convert.ToString(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column3"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_precio", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column4"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_valtotal", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column5"].Value));
    guardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column6"].Value = codigofactura.Text));
    guardar.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Donde le estas diciendo que lo recorra hasta que sea menor que el total de filas `-1` y ahora en vez de obtener los datos así:

> `row.Cells["column1"].Value`

Lo debes hacer así:

> `tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnX.."].Value`

---

Si quieres seguir usando el `foreach`, solo debes validar que se ejecute tu código dentro del ciclo, si la fila no esta vacía:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tblarticulo.Rows)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["column1"].Value.ToSring()))
    {
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: me aparece error en (tblarticulo.Rows[i]["column1"]));

Comment: @CarlosFernandez he editado mi respuesta, si había cometido un error en la sintaxis, ya está..

Comment: listo me funciono. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @CarlosFernandez me alegra, si te ha funcionado, podría considerar [votar a favor a la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)?

Comment: no me deja votar

Comment: @CarlosFernandez si cierto, debes tener _una reputación de 15_  al menos para poder hacerlo. :)

Answer (score 0):

En lo personal no me gusta tener la fila, y siempre se la quito para no tener problemas posteriores, además de que se ve mejor sin ella.

Si se la quitas igual solucionarías tu error, la linea de codigo para ya no tener dicha fila es:

```
tblarticulo.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Siendo `tblarticulo` un `DataGridView` esta linea debería ir después de crear tu objeto, también podria ir en el constructor de tu ´Form´.

Ej:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tblarticulo.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}
```

Con eso la ultima fila de tu `DataGridView` ya no seria visible y se solucionaría tu error.

Comment: Esta es la solución principal que pensé, pero... en la pregunta dice: _"Tengo un DataGridView en el cual ingreso datos **directamente**"_ supongo que se refiere a que ingresa los datos manualmente, por lo tanto esa fila debe estar para poder hacer esto...